# Host unreachable from a specific host

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firewall, virtual-machines, proxmox

I'm encountering a weird issue where connections from one VM (A) to another VM (B) systematically time out, in both ways. Symptoms:

1. `ping A` from `B` hangs (as well as anything else I have tried such as ssh, http, netcat etc.)
2. `ping B` from `A` hangs crashes with a `ping: Do you want to ping broadcast? Then -b. If not, check your local firewall rules`
3. `ping -b B` from `A` hangs just as in step 1

A and B are ubuntu VMs running on the same Proxmox Node. Both can successfully reach other hosts over the internet. Their network configuration seems identical to me, apart from their static IP (the last digit changes).

Now, this is where it gets confusing to me. I have a third ubuntu VM (C) on the same proxmox node, and:

1. Ping from C to A and from A to C works fine.
2. Ping from C to B and from B to C works fine.

The network configuration for each VM is shown below:

## Server A config

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [xx.xx.xx.224/28]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: xx.xx.xx.254
        on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
        search: []
  version: 2

agate@server-A:~$ ifconfig
ens18: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xx.xx.224  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast xx.xx.xx.239
        inet6 fe80::ff:feca:9d50  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:00:00:ca:9d:50  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 44792791  bytes 147553446480 (147.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 42577292  bytes 41365334680 (41.3 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

## Server B config

```
agate@server-B:~$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [xx.xx.xx.226/28]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: xx.xx.xx.254
        on-link: true
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
        search: []
  version: 2

agate@server-B:~$ ifconfig
ens18: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xx.xx.226  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast xx.xx.xx.239
        inet6 fe80::ff:fe4f:96ab  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:00:00:4f:96:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 102583  bytes 8681631 (8.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 219135  bytes 218634003 (218.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

## Server C config

```
agate@server-C:~$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [xx.xx.xx.225/28]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: xx.xx.xx.254
        on-link: true
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
        search: []
  version: 2

agate@server-C:~$ ifconfig

ens18: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xx.xx.225  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast xx.xx.xx.239
        inet6 fe80::ff:fec3:f9e5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:00:00:c3:f9:e5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 103612  bytes 19973364 (19.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35103  bytes 159749390 (159.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

## ping and tcpdump results

I've tried to narrow down the issue but I'm not good at networking. If I use tcpdump on `B`, and try a ping from `A`, I get this:

```
agate@server-A:~$ ping xx.xx.xx.226
PING xx.xx.xx.226 56(84) bytes of data.
# hangs
--- xx.xx.xx.226 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2038ms
```

```shell
# xx.xx.xx.224 is server A ip address
agate@server-B:~$ sudo tcpdump -n "src xx.xx.xx.224"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens18, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
03:40:20.261054 IP xx.xx.xx.224 > xx.xx.xx.226: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 1, length 64
03:40:21.279229 IP xx.xx.xx.224 > xx.xx.xx.226: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 2, length 64
03:40:22.303190 IP xx.xx.xx.224 > xx.xx.xx.226: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 3, length 64
```

So it looks like packets are arriving from `A` to `B`. Doing the same thing but in reverse (tcpdump on `B`, ping from `A`) yields a different result though:

```
agate@server-B:~$ ping xx.xx.xx.224
ping: Do you want to ping broadcast? Then -b. If not, check your local firewall rules
```

Using `ping -b xx.xx.xx.224` generate the following `tcpdump` output on `A` (and hangs on B, with a 100% packet loss):

```shell
# xx.xx.xx.226 is server B ip address
agate@apps:~$ sudo tcpdump -n "src xx.xx.xx.226"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on ens18, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
03:46:31.369889 IP xx.xx.xx..226 > xx.xx.xx..224: ICMP echo request, id 5, seq 1, length 64
03:46:32.376541 IP xx.xx.xx..226 > xx.xx.xx..224: ICMP echo request, id 5, seq 2, length 64
03:46:33.450877 IP xx.xx.xx..226 > xx.xx.xx..224: ICMP echo request, id 5, seq 3, length 64
```

Since ping from B to A generates a firewall related message that is not present in the opposite direction, my current guess is that there is some firewall configuration on B that breaks connection between A and B.

I've tried to disable ufw (via `sudo ufw disable`) on both A and B to see if it changed anything. It didn't. What can I do to pinpoint the issue further?

Comment: remind, that Proxmox has also some kind of Firewall Features by default enabled.

Comment: @djdomi indeed! as far as I can tell, it was already disabled, but I disabled it explicitely at the VM/Node/Datacenter level in the UI and by running ` pve-firewall stop` on the Proxmox node, with no luck :/

Comment: you need to add, which hoster is used? is the hidden ip a public ip? do you use a routed or bridged setup? The Host was not shown iirc

Comment: This is one of the services on server A : https://status.agate.blue/ (IP 92.222.119.224)
This is one of the services on server B : https://cloud.mutu.fr.eu.org/ (IP 92.222.119.226)
This is one of the services on server C : https://mx.agate.blue/ (IP 92.222.119.225)
As you can see, all are hosted on public IPs, the same ones defined in the netplan configuration.

VMs are configured in bridge mode in proxmox, the proxmox node itself is hosted at OVH.

Comment: thank you for the update, i ask this information, due the fac that it makes differences from the host, how to let the other communicate. For Example: Netcup does only allow the MAC of the HOST to communicate. If a non-Host MAC tries to communicate  it will fail. And thats why its importance about the config of your host